# Calculating the times in minutes between two times, factoring in business hours in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel

I'm looking to calculate how many minutes passed between two times/dates. I only need to know how many minutes passed between the business hours of 08:00 and 18:00.
For example if the first date/time is 01-01-22 17:00 and the second time/date is 02-01-22 09:00, 120 would be the result, as the formula would count from 01-01-22 17:00 to 01-01-22 18:00 (60 minutes), and then 02-01-22 08:00 to 02-01-22 09:00 (60 minutes), giving the answer of 120.
Is this even possible with a forumla, or would it need some scripting?

Comment: Substract one from the other? What have you tried?

Comment: I've currently got =TEXT(AA13-Z13,"[mm]") which shows me the time in minutes between the two times/dates. Ok, ive figured it out, just minus 14 hours (1800-0800) from that!

Answer (score 0):

Using Office 365 we can use SEQUENCE to create an array of all the minutes between the two times.  Then test whether they land during office hours and sum up the results:

```
=LET(
    SQ,SEQUENCE((AA13-Z13)*24*60-1,,A1*24*60),
    MD,MOD(SQ/(24*60),1),
    SUM((MD>TIME(8,0,0))*(MD<=TIME(18,0,0))))
```

[image]